# Trying to link one javascript event to another

Tags: javascript, html, audio, slideshow

I am currently modifying a web app for iPad. I am trying to attach an audio soundtrack to the image slideshow. I currently have the audio files playing when the user hits the slideshow navigation controls but I can't seem to figure out how to make the audio play when the slides have automatically started.

When the nextBg() function in my main.js file moves from the current background image to the next I want it to play the next audio file in the list. The play function is: playAudio(). How do I do this?

The codes and files I am currently working with are:

```
function nextBg() {
    if(bgRunning) return false;
    clearInterval(bgTimer);
    if(!$('#bgImages li.active').is(':last-child'))
        $('#bgImages li.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    else
        $('#bgImages li.active').removeClass('active').parent().find('li:first-child').addClass('active');
    runBg();
}

function playAudio(path){
    if(audioSupport){
        var isPlaying = !myAudio.paused;
        var canPlayMp3 = !!myAudio.canPlayType && "" != myAudio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg');
        var canPlayOgg = !!myAudio.canPlayType && "" != myAudio.canPlayType('audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"');
        if(canPlayMp3)
            myAudio.src = path+'.mp3';
        else if(canPlayOgg)
            myAudio.src = path+'.ogg';


        myAudio.removeEventListener('ended', arguments.callee, false);
        myAudio.addEventListener('ended', audioAddEndedListener , false);

        if(autoPlay || isPlaying)
        {
            myAudio.play();
            $('#audioControls .pause').css('display','block');
            $('#audioControls .play').css('display','none');
        }else{
            $('#audioControls .play').css('display','block');
            $('#audioControls .pause').css('display','none');
        }
    }
}

function audioAddEndedListener() 
{
    if(loop){
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
    }else{
        this.removeEventListener('ended', arguments.callee, false);
        setNextAudio();
        path = $('#audioList li.active').html();
        playAudio(path);
        myAudio.addEventListener('ended', audioAddEndedListener, false);
    }
}
```

- http://platinum.megatron.co.nz/main.js
- http://platinum.megatron.co.nz/kitchen/video.html

Answer (score 1):

Just call your playAudio() method inside the playBg() method after you swap the image.

Comment: I tried the following:

`// Background Image Play Button
function playBg(){
 clearInterval(bgTimer);
 $('#bgControl .play').hide();
 $('#bgControl .pause').show();
 path = $('#audioList li.active').html();
 playAudio(path);
 bgPaused = false;
 if(activePlayer=='youtube')
  ytplayer.playVideo();
 else if(activePlayer=='vimeo')
  $f(vmplayer).api('play');
 else
  nextBg();
}`

Is that what you meant? The audio still doesn't change on transition.

Comment: Well basing on what I've seen in your code, you will want to pass the next path to your playAudio() method with each new call. The easiest way to do this would be to have your audio files be numbered and to increment the number with each call to the playAudio() method.

For instance, if your path is "music/file", in the beginning of the playAudio() method (and let's say you have 5 different audio files, and you have a counter variable named "count") you can put:
if (count < 5)
  ++count;
else
  count = 1;

then:
path = "music/file" + count;